# How can I get Messages app?

Tags: macos, messages

I deleted my Messages app but I'm not sure how to re-install it.
What can I do?
I'm on 10.9.1 by the way.

Comment: How did you delete it, maybe it is still there.

Comment: I deleted it with AppCleaner. As far as I can tell it's gone, can't see it on my applications folder nor the launchpad.

Comment: Did you keep a copy of the maverics installer (5.3 gig) use it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a backup

If you have a Time Machine backup (or other backup of the system), you can restore the file from there. Browse to the folder in Finder and enter Time Machine, go back in time until the file is found then restore it.

#### Copy the file from another system or a trusted person's machine

If you have a second machine with a comparable build of OS X installed on it, you can copy the file from it. Feel free to ask for the checksum of a file in chat to compare it to if you wish to make sure that the file is correct (not modified accidentally/purposefully).

#### Pacifist with OS X install media

If you've got an OS X install media and [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com), you can browse the install media and grab the file.

[image]

If you have Pacifist but no install media, it will prompt you to download the installer.

[image]

#### Reinstall OS X

If you've got the ability to reinstall OS X through the Recovery HD, Internet Recovery or an OS X install media then reinstalling OS X will 'repair' your install and copy any missing/broken system files back to your system.